# What do these parentheses inserted after "Pretty Print" with StandardForm?

Tags: output-formatting, syntax

### Background:

I have a list containing individual elements and sublists.

```
tab = {1, 2, 3, a, {4, 1}, {5, 2}}
```

The individual elements are also to be converted into sublists with -1 as second element. The already existing sublists should not be changed. The expected result is:

> {{1, -1}, {2, -1}, {3, -1}, {a, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 2}}

The task can be done easily with a Replace command. This command only operates on level 1, and excludes elements that are lists through a condition.

```
tab2 = Replace[tab, x_ /; ! ListQ[x] :> {x, -1}, {1}]
```

To work further on the condition, I have converted the call to ListQ into a pure function that calls ListQ in turn.

```
tab2 = Replace[tab, x_ /; ! ListQ[#] &[x] :> {x, -1}, {1}]
```

### Observation:

At this point I have converted the input cell into the [StandardForm (Doc here)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/StandardForm.html) for syntax checking. and some kind of pretty printing. The change from # to #1 is easy to understand. In addition, a pair of round brackets was inserted. When I convert into the InputForm, the results are identical except for some other spacing.

```
tab2 = Replace[tab, x_ /; ! ListQ[#] &[x] :> {x, -1}, {1}] (*Version 1*)
tab2 = Replace[tab, (x_ /; ! ListQ[#1] &)[x] :> {x, -1}, {1}] (*Version 1 converted*)
```

The position of the left bracket did not convince me completely. I have therefore experimented with other bracket positions. I obtained the following results after the respective conversion.

```
tab2 = Replace[tab, x_ /; (! ListQ[#1] &)[x] :> {x, -1}, {1}] (*Version 2*)
tab2 = Replace[tab, x_ /; (! ListQ[#1] &)[x] :> {x, -1}, {1}] (*Version 2 converted*)

tab2 = Replace[tab, x_ /; (! ListQ[#1] &[x]) :> {x, -1}, {1}] (*Version 3*)
tab2 = Replace[tab, x_ /; (! ListQ[#1] &)[x] :> {x, -1}, {1}] (*Version 3 converted*)

tab2 = Replace[tab, (x_ /; ! ListQ[#1] &[x]) :> {x, -1}, {1}] (*Version 4*)
tab2 = Replace[tab, (x_ /; ! ListQ[#1] &)[x] :> {x, -1}, {1}] (*Version 4 converted*)
```

Version 2 only includes the pure function definition in brackets. This position of the left bracket is apparently also recognized as good and not changed during the conversion. If I move the right bracket past [x] (versions 3 and 4), it is moved back by the conversion. All 4 versions, both unconverted and converted, can be executed without errors, and deliver the same result.

### Question:

I do not assume that the Mathematica kernel inserts the brackets during the conversion for purely cosmetic reasons.

Is there any documentation about what effect the brackets at this point of the statement have?